# Excel "IF" Statements Across Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to make a IF Statement with a (80%) or .80 threshold to check across 5 columns.

```
1            2           3           4          5

0.821282128 0.118611861 0.02990299  0.0070007   0.02320232
```

I tried using this:

```
=IF(E130>0.8, "A", IF(F130>0.8, "B", IF(G130>0.8, "C", IF(H130>0.8, "D", IF(I130>0.8, "E")))))

=IF(AND(E30>0.8),"A",IF(AND(F30>0.8),"B",IF(AND(G30>0.8),"C",IF(AND(H30>0.8),"D",IF(AND(I30>0.8),"E","NA")))))
```

Having trouble to getting this statement to work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to find the first match? If so you can use this formula which will expand more easily for larger ranges if required

`=INDEX({"A","B","C","D","E"},MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(E130:H130>0.8,0),0))`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are missing the clause in the E where you produce a blank if its not found:

```
=IF(E130>0.8, "A", IF(F130>0.8, "B", IF(G130>0.8, "C", IF(H130>0.8, "D", IF(I130>0.8, "E", "")))))
```

I confirmed it otherwise works, but if all 5 cells are less or equal to 0.8, you get FALSE.